# How to open the previous url from the history in a new tab in Vimperator

Tags: firefox, vimperator

In normal Firefox, I can open the previous history item in a new tab by middle clicking the back button in the location bar.

Does Vimperator have a keyboard shortcut to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

### New tab - then history

One is to open a tab, then go back in history:

- `:tabopen` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a tab.
- `:history` <kbd>Space</kbd> to open the interactive history list. Then you can <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the entry you want and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open it.

This history pane is also searchable, so you can start typing the something that matches the history entry you want to go back to to find it more easily.

### History - then new tab

Another way is to trigger the history navigation and then load the entry you want in a tab.

- `:history` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the full history list.
- <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> to scroll etc.
- When you can see what you want <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> fires up the new tab overlay. You can type to filter as usual with following a link and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to load the match, or filter down until only one remains.

## EDIT:

### Duplicate tab - then go back

After some thought, I realised the following is probably closest to what is being asked:

- `:tabduplicate` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a new duplicate tab of the current tab.
- `:back` <kbd>Space</kbd> to open the tab's back history. Then you can <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the entry you want. If you know you want the most recent entry, you can just do `:back` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This is still not exactly what I had in mind because vimperators `:history` is shared between tabs unlike the back button in the location bar but it is good enough for my browsing habits.

Comment: I've added a 3rd option which I think is closest to what you're looking for - hope it helps.

Comment: The third option is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try pressing `u`
or use the `undo` function

Comment: That only restores the last closed tab. I want to create a new tab with the last history item of the current tab.

Answer (score 0):

### `:backt` and `:forwardt` commands

I provided a full solution for this [here](https://superuser.com/a/914124/122411) (both for Pentadactyl and Vimperator). You can download the Vimperator source from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/troyp/b4b4b75a0ef59a986e94). Sourcing it will provide you with `:backt` and `:forwardt` commands, which are also accessible via the bindings <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>.